# Counting possible combinations to open a lock( 2006 ACM ICPC)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I was working on a problem in a coding competition and I began to wonder about the analytical (mathematical) solution to this problem. I am not even sure how to go about counting this. Any ideas will be helpful. 
Link to the problem: http://www.acmgnyr.org/year2006/d.pdf

I am pasting the problem here, in case you don't want to click the link. Sorry about the length! The question says write a code, but I am just curious about how to do it mathematically without writing code.

A push button door lock consists of a number of push buttons  B. The lock is opened by pressing the  correct sequence of button combinations and then turning the doorknob. If the sequence of presses is correct, the door magically opens. A combination consists of 1 or more buttons being pressed simultaneously. A sequence consists of a series of combinations. A sequence must have at least one combination. Once a button  has been used in a combination,it may not be used again in the same sequence. In addition, it is  not necessary to use all the buttons in a sequence. For example, for 
`B=8: 
(1-2-3)(4)(7-8)`
is a valid sequence with 3 combinations `(1-2-3)`, `(4)`, and `(7-8)`. Note that buttons 5 and  6 are not used in this sequence. `(1-2-3)(2-4)(5-6)` 
is not a valid sequence, since button 2 appears in 2 combinations `(1-2-3)` and `(2-4)`. Write a program that  determines the number of valid sequences possible for given values of B.

When $B=3$ there are 25 sequences and when $B=4$, there are 149 sequences.

Comment: I'm trying to work out that for $B=3$ there are 45 sequences, as you stated.  But I keep coming up with 25.  They break down as: Pattern (x) : 3 sequences; Pattern (x)(y) : 6 sequences;  Pattern (x-y) : 3 sequences;  Pattern (x)(y)(z) : 6 sequences; Pattern (x-y)(z): 3 sequences; Pattern (x)(y-z) : 3 sequences; Pattern (x-y-z) : 1 sequence.  Am I missing something?  I'm assuming that in presenting a 'combination' order is unimportant since the buttons are pressed simultaneously.  For instance combination (1-2) is the same as combination (2-1).

Comment: The actual pdf the poster links to says there are 25 sequences when n=3.  I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Yup, my bad!! sorry about that!! It definitely is 25!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $B'=B\cup\{\infty\}$, where $\infty$ isn't a button. If you partition $B'$ into $k>1$ sets, that determines $k-1$ combinations - the partition with $\infty$ isn't counted - and there are $(k-1)!$ ways to order those combinations into a sequence. So $$\sum_{k=2}^{|B|+1} (k-1)!p_k(B')$$ is the count required, where $p_k(X)$ is the number of ways of partitioning a set $X$ into $k$ non-empty sets.

Now $p_n(X)=S(|X|,k)$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number_of_the_second_kind). So if $n=|B|$ then $|B'|=n+1$ and we get the numbers:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} (k-1)!S(n+1,k)$$

Using data from Wikipedia, we have $S(4,2)=7,S(4,3)=6,S(4,4)=1$. That yields, for $|B|=3$, the formulation:

$$1!\cdot 7 + 2!\cdot 6 + 3!\cdot 1 = 25$$

which is the value posted by user paw in comments, and disagrees with your 45.

For $n=1,2,3$ we get $1,5,25$, which is interesting.

For $|B|=4$, though, we get:

$$1!\cdot 15+2!\cdot 25 +3!\cdot 10 + 4!\cdot 1 = 149$$

Wikipedia's formula for $S(n,k)$ might be useful:

$$S(n,k) =\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}j^n$$

Yielding:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j} \binom{k}{j}j^{n+1}$$

A slightly different counting approach gives:

$$1+2\sum_{k=2}^n k!S(n,k)$$

For example, when $n=4$ this is $$1+2\left( 2!\cdot S(4,2)+3!\cdot S(4,3)+4!\cdot S(4,4)\right)=1+2\cdot 74=149$$

(The counting argument is as follows. We take a partition of $B$ into $k$ parts. We can use either all $k$ parts as combinations, in any order, or, when $k>1$, we can also use only $k-1$ parts. That gives us $2k!$ answers contributed by this partition.)

This formula might be better because Wikipedia says that:

$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} k!\cdot S(n,k)$$ is something called the $n$th "ordered Bell number," and the count we are looking for, for $n>0$, is thus equal to $2a_n-1$. Ordered Bell numbers (or Fubini numbers) are listed on the OEIS page as sequence number [A000670](https://oeis.org/A000670).

Comment: I think your second sentence isn't quite right... I'm having a problem understanding that line (and that line only).

Comment: @anorton It's fine, assuming I understand it correctly.  Suppose there are seven buttons.  The partition $\{1, 2, 3\}\{4, 5\}\{6\}\{7, \infty\}$ gives rise to $3!$ different combination sequences.  None of those combination sequences uses the button 7.

Comment: Basically, the partition parts are the "combinations," except for the part containing $\infty$, which is the set of buttons that are never pressed. So, with $k$ parts, there are $k-1$ combinations, and thus $(k-1)!$ different ways to order them.

Comment: Ah ha!  That helped a lot, thanks! :)  (+1 in an hour when I get my votes back...)

Comment: It seems to make sense, but when I substitute the values, it doesn't add up. For n=3, reading the numbers from Wikipedia I get 1!.7 + 2!.6 + 3!.1 which is not 45. Am I missing something?

Comment: The formula gets 149 for $n=4$, so I think there was a typo in the problem, or, if you enumerated tha answer for $B=3$ yourself, you got it wrong. @user1775614